# How to open up the list of players currently online in a Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have noticed several times on Youtube videos that players would hit some key on their keyboard to open up a list of players on the server they are playing on.

The list denotes the usernames and the connection strength that each player has.

My question is: **How do I open that list? Is it a command? Or a key?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press and hold <kbd>tab</kbd>, while in a server, to view a menu detailing the names and player skins of everyone online.

Another way to do this is to scroll over the WiFi picture, in the corner, while in the server list. This will show you the players currently in the server, if that server is at maximum capacity.

Answer (score 6):

You can do so simply by hitting the "**Tab**" key on your keyboard.

Comment: This button is [configurable](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Controls#Configurable_controls) in the control options. It is called "List Players".